# Passing Params to a 301 redirect in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm stuck on a Rails 2.3 app trying to redirect some old URLs.  I'm new to RoR and know 3+ way better, so I'm having trouble getting this done.

So: **http://siteurl.com/foo/:foo_id** goes to **http://siteurl.com/foo/:foo_id/foo_items**

I think I'm close because the end product goes to: **http://siteurl.com/foo/foo_id/foo_items** but doesn't pass the `:foo_id` params it actually writes it out!

Any help, or pointers are much appreciated.

In my routes.rb

```
map.connect '/foo/:foo_id',
      :controller => 'redirect',
      :action => :redirectoldfoo,
      :monkey_tag => ':foo_id'
```

In my redirect controller:

```
  def redirectoldfoo
    redirect_to "/auctions/#{params[:monkey_tag]}/catalog_items"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need the `:monkey_tag` at all, since `:foo_id` is all you're using anyway.

```
  map.connect '/foo/:foo_id',
      :controller => 'redirect',
      :action => :redirectoldfoo

  def redirectoldfoo
    redirect_to "/auctions/#{params[:foo_id]}/catalog_items"
  end
```

Note that in your example you indicated that you were trying to redirect to both `/foo/:foo_id/foo_items` and then `/auctions/:foo_id/catalog_items`. I assumed that the second one was closer to the real code, so I left that one in there.

Comment: A+. I'm always overcomplicating

Comment: I realize I'm late to the party, but how would this work for making http://www.siteurl.com into http://siteurl.com ? This would be a huge help for an old Rails project I'm fixing.

Comment: Hi @KDP. You should handle that in the web server if possible, but it is possible to do it in Rails as well. Either way, this is well traveled ground with plenty of answers on this site as well as serverfault.com.